# Shouldn't it segfault? Why is there a "pointer being freed was not allocated" error?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have two questions about the following code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char    *ft_strnew(size_t size)
{
    char        *result;
    size_t      i;

    result = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    if (result)
    {
        i = size;
        while (i > 0)
        {
            result[i - 1] = '\0';
            i = i - 1;
        }
    }
    return (result);
}

int     main(void)
{
    char    *test;

    test = ft_strnew(1);
    if (test)
    {
        test[2] = '\0';
        test[1] = '1';
        test[0] = '1';
        printf("%s", test);
        //free(&test);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

When I run `gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -o test ft_strnew.c && ./test` I get :

```
11%
```

And if I uncomment the line containing the `free()` call in my `main()` I get :

```
test(27744,0x7fff7941d300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff558b16d0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
11zsh: abort      ./test
```

### 1- Why in the first case doesn't it segfault?

The size of the `char *` i create is `(1 * sizeof(char))`.
But I can add three chars `('1', '1', '\0')` inside it.

Shouldn't it segfault?

### 2- Why in the second case is there the free problem?

It occures even if I create a `char *` with passing 3 to `ft_strnew()`.
I create the `char *` with a `malloc()` call, shouldn't the memory be allocated?

Comment: How many dups of this crap need to exist before devs stop posting it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, yet again, asking for an explanation of something already known to be grossly incorrect.   This subclass of Tstupid is 'TarrayBoundsStupid'.

Comment: @MartinJames I apologize for having bothered you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1- Why in the first case doesn't it segfault?

It causes undefined behavior, which permits anything. The program might work as expected, it might segfault... anything.

> 2- Why in the second case is there the free problem?

You attempt to free the address **of the pointer**, not the address of the `malloc`ated area. `free(test)` should work fine.

Comment: You seems to be right for the (2), my bad that was stupid. For the (1) I though if I tried to access an adress I didn't allocate it should automatically segfault, so it's only a risk?.

Comment: @vmonteco Yes. The C standard has no notion of "segmentation faults." It just knows about undefined, implementation-defined, unspecified, well-defined (and maybe something else I forgot) behavior.

Comment: I didn't know that! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One reason why overrunning an array returned from `malloc()` (or `calloc()` or `new` or any other similar dynamic memory function) doesn't always result in any failure at all is because of this statement in the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> **7.20.3 Memory management functions**
>
> ...  The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is **suitably
>   aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object**
>   and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in
>   the space allocated. ...

In practice, that means `malloc()` will return memory in discrete chunks that match the most restrictive alignment requirements of your system.  For example, this may be 8 bytes if objects such as `double` or `long long` values are restricted to addresses that are multiples of 8 bytes.  So if you `malloc()` 1 byte you actually get 8 and can "get away with" overrunning the buffer by up to 7 bytes.  Any if you `malloc()` 11 bytes you get 16 in reality.  But if you `malloc()` 32 bytes you actually get exactly 32 bytes and can't "get away with" overrunning your buffer at all.